# Simple way for scrolling text using C++

Tags: c++

I want to make a simple program in C++ and I need to scroll some text through the window. I looked up on some sited and I only found complex methods to do it. I don't want to use any of these complex methods for this simple program. Does anyone know a easy way to do that?

Comment: Considering there's no standard, portable way to scroll text, any solution is going to have some complexity associated with it.

Comment: You could tell us what those complex options were

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a very simple function to scroll text on the screen in C++, you can use the following method,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

void pushX(int num){
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
        cout<<" ";
}
int main() {
    for(int j=0;j<50;j++){
        system("CLS");
        pushX(j);
        cout<<"Hello";
        Sleep(100);
    }

}
```

Happy coding.

**Note:** Windows Only

Comment: Nice and simple :). Windows only though.

Comment: Ya. I cant think of a simpler way.

Comment: By the way, `pushX` can be replaced with a `std::string` construction if you don't care about the cost of doing that every iteration (which is likely to be the case with output and a `system` call). `std::cout  << std::string(j, ' ');`